# SQL - How can I use a Select based on the parameter

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, parameter-passing

I've got a sql statement in a SQL Server stored procedure using a where clause like this:

```
Select (fields)
From Table
Where Testname like @SearchLetter + '%'
```

I need to do check the parameter `@SearchLetter` and if it's "#", I need to make the parameter choose records that the field `Testname` starts with a numeric field (0-9)

I've tried several things (ifs/selects, etc.) but I can't seem to get what I need.

anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Add sample data and expected result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
where Testname like case @SearchLetter
    when '#' then '[0-9]' + '%'
    else @Searchletter + '%' end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Where Testname like REPLACE(@SearchLetter, '#', '[0-9]') + '%'
```

Assuming that the string is always one character (or that you always want this substitution to occur wherever the hash falls) Otherwise use a `CASE` statement to check for exact equality.

```
Where Testname like 
 CASE WHEN @SearchLetter = '#' 
  THEN '[0-9]'
  ELSE @SearchLetter 
 END + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is

```
where left(@SearchLetter, 1) between '0' and '9
```

Comment: This is testing the first letter of the variable. They want to test the first letter of the column conditional on the variable value.